# clear IP-addresses from Joomla 2.5.4 log file

Tags: logging, joomla, admin, ip-address

I have access to a Joomla administrator panel as the super user. I would like to clear the log where the IP-addresses of the people who log in to the admin panel are stored. The thing is that i don't have the log in and password for the PHPmyadmin of the site nor do i have access to the ftp of the site.

Is there any way i can clear the log without needing PHP log in/password or ftp log in/password?

There were some posts about this before but they were featuring Joomla 1.5 ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, Joomla! does not create such a log. So you have to identify, who exactly is logging here: Is it the webserver? Is it an extension?

Once you have identified the logger and know, where the log is stored, you probably can use that tool to clear the log. If that tool does not provide such access, as a super admin, you have some options.

### Database

To get access to the database, install an extension, eg. [Art Adminer](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=artadminer). It is small and fast, but not the Joomla! way. It works, but be sure to remove it after use. I haven't analyzed its code yet and thus don't assume it being safe and secure.

### File System

There are tools for file access, too, eg [eXtplorer](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=extplorer). This tool fits much better into Joomla! than Adminer.

### Conclusion

If you think you have to use tools that allow access to the low level components like database and filesystem, always be aware that **you can easily destroy the system** by manually changing anything. So **take a backup** first, and **remove such extensions** again as soon as possible. Otherwise they may create security issues.